# I can't see some databases even though my user has the "root" role

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.0

I installed MongoDB 3.2 and I enabled authentication:

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

I created an admin user with the following command in the terminal:

```
mongo admin --eval 'db.createUser({user:"admin",pwd:"password",roles:["root"]})'
```

Then I created new database and a user for this database using the following command:

```
mongo -u admin -p password admin --eval 'db.getSiblingDB("shop").createUser({user:"shop_user",pwd:"password",roles:["dbOwner"]})'
```

Everything seem to be working. When I'm logged in with the **shop_user** user I can do everything in the **shop** database and I can only see this database. But when I'm logged in with the **admin** user I cannot see the **shop** database. Since the **admin** user has the **root** role, I assume I should be able to see all the databases in my system, but the **shop** database is hidden from me.

Does anybody know what is happening and how I can make the **admin** user see all databases?

Comment: I re-pro your steps and I was able to access **shop** database with both **admin** and **shop_user**. When you log in with **admin**, did you specify to use **shop** database with `use shop`?

Comment: Also, you may want to post output of `use admin; show users` and `use shop; show users`

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have not restarted your MongoDB instance in **auth mode**. 
Restart your MongoDB in auth mode in linux like this

```
mongod --auth --fork --logpath /var/log/mongod.log
```

***Reference:*** [Enable Auth](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/)

Remember if you have enabled auth mode for your MongoDB instance, you must have put it in your code and start the mongod process in auth mode.

To simplify this (authenticating the db) use [Studio 3T](https://studio3t.com/) (MongoDB Client) but you still need to start the instance with the `--auth` command line option.

Comment: What if I installed mongoDB as a daemon on Ubuntu 18 and restart it using `sudo systemctl restart mongodb`? How do I ensure it is started in auth mode always from now on, since I've enabled authorization in the config?